# In UITableview the typed textfield values is getting repeated in different cells ,how to rectify that using objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uitextfield

I am new to objective c in my tableview i populated the textfield dynamically in the uitableview cell its working fine but whenever the user types the values in the uitextfield the value get repeated to another cell textfield can anyone help me how to solve this error.This is my sample code and i also the added the sample screen shot below for your reference .
[image: tableview screen shot]

```
 #import "TableViewController.h"
    #import "TableViewCell.h"
    @interface TableViewController ()<UITableViewDelegate>
    @end
    @implementation TableViewController
    - (void)viewDidLoad {
        [super viewDidLoad];
        self.mytableview.dataSource=self;
        self.mytableview.delegate=self;
    }
    - (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {

        return 1;
    }

    - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
        return 20;
    }
    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
        static NSString *cellidentifier=@"cell";
        TableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellidentifier];
        if (!cell) {
            cell= [[TableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellidentifier];



           }
        return cell;
    }


    @end
```

Comment: Please update your question. I can't see the image and where is your textfield?

Comment: thanks for your reply i updated my question

Comment: I need to see your code which sets up `UITextField` to help you resolve issue.

Comment: In tableview custom cell class                                                                      [@interface TableViewCell : UITableViewCell
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *textfield;]

Comment: Your problem is when you type some text in a text field , this text appears on another textfield too, right? Did you use any method of UITextFieldDelegate?

Comment: no sir i didn't use

Comment: And your problem is when you type some text in a text field , this text appears on another textfield too, right?

Comment: s sir absolutely

Comment: Can you show me `TableViewCell .m`  file?

Comment: i didn't use any function in tableviewcell.m only the default uicustomcell code is there

Comment: You type some text in a cell and after that, you scroll tableView, this text appear on another cell. Is this right problem? Maybe you describe wrong in your answer.

Comment: s sir absolutely i am having the same problem what you mentioned in the previous reply can u please solve that problem

Comment: I have added an answer, you can check it )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, text appears on another cell because the cell is reused when you create cell by `TableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellidentifier]`

Add this code to your `TableViewCell.m`

```
- (void)prepareForReuse {
    self.textfield.text = @"";
}
```

`TableViewController.m`

```
#import "TableViewController.h"
#import "TableViewCell.h"

#define numberOfRow         20;

@interface TableViewController ()<UITableViewDelegate, UITextFieldDelegate>
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray* texts;
@end
@implementation TableViewController
- (void)viewDidLoad {
  [super viewDidLoad];
  _texts = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

  for (int i = 0; i < numberOfRow; i++) {
    [_texts addObject:@""];
  }

  self.mytableview.dataSource=self;
  self.mytableview.delegate=self;
}
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {

  return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
  return numberOfRow;
}
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
  static NSString *cellidentifier=@"cell";
  TableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellidentifier];
  if (!cell) {
    cell= [[TableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellidentifier];
  }

  cell.textField.text = _texts[indexPath.row];
  cell.textField.tag = indexPath.row;
  cell.textField.delegate = self;

  return cell;
}

- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
  _text[textField.tag] = textField.text;
}
@end
```

Comment: By using this code the cell values is not repeating but the typed values are hiding .

Comment: Text disappear after you scroll because you don't save text after typing. Create an array an save text each time text in cell change. I have updated my answer, check again

Comment: Welcome @user19 :D

Comment: I have one more doubt,I am getting same issues for Uibutton can u please suggest me how to solve that issue

Comment: First, create a array to contain button title like i did with `texts` array. Set title of button in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`. In `prepareForReuse` set title of button to @"". You can try it ;)